# Split a list into nested list at the points where item matches the criteria

Tags: python

**I've a list like this in python:**

```
['name: "Ship_Date"',
 'type: STRING',
 'num_non_missing: 100000',
 'name: "Units_Sold"',
 'type: FLOAT',
 'num_non_missing: 100000',
 'tot_num_values: 100000',
 'name: "Order_Date"'
 'type: FLOAT',
 'num_non_missing: 100000',
 'name: "Region"',
 'type: STRING',
 'num_non_missing: 100000',
 'tot_num_values: 100000',
 'name: "Item_Type"',
 'type: STRING',
 'num_non_missing: 100000',
 'tot_num_values: 100000']
```

**Now I want to split this list at the point where 'name:' is present.**

**I want output like below:**

```
[['name: "Ship_Date"',
 'type: STRING',
 'num_non_missing: 100000'],
['name: "Units_Sold"',
 'type: FLOAT',
 'num_non_missing: 100000',
 'tot_num_values: 100000'],
['name: "Order_Date"'
 'type: FLOAT',
 'num_non_missing: 100000'],
['name: "Region"',
 'type: STRING',
 'num_non_missing: 100000',
 'tot_num_values: 100000'],
['name: "Item_Type"',
 'type: STRING',
 'num_non_missing: 100000',
 'tot_num_values: 100000']]
```

**Please let me know if the problem is not clear enough. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You should try with your code first, bro.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which code problem do you need help with?

Comment: I've tried this below code, but not really getting the expected output
`r = [[]] 
for i in new_list:
    if 'name' in i:
        r.append([i])
    else:
        r[-1].append([i])
r`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
start = 0
new_lst = []
for i,elem in enumerate(x):
    if elem.startswith('name'):
        end = i
        sublst = x[start:end]
        if sublst:
            new_lst.append(sublst)
        start = i
new_lst.append(x[start:])
```

Output:

```
[['name: "Ship_Date"', 'type: STRING', 'num_non_missing: 100000'],
 ['name: "Units_Sold"',
  'type: FLOAT',
  'num_non_missing: 100000',
  'tot_num_values: 100000'],
 ['name: "Order_Date"type: FLOAT', 'num_non_missing: 100000'],
 ['name: "Region"',
  'type: STRING',
  'num_non_missing: 100000',
  'tot_num_values: 100000'],
 ['name: "Item_Type"',
  'type: STRING',
  'num_non_missing: 100000',
  'tot_num_values: 100000']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This also worked for me.

```
from itertools import groupby
li = ['abc',1,2,3,'abc',5,6,7,8,9000,10,11,12,1300]
class GroupbyHelper(object):
   def __init__(self, val):
       self.val = val
       self.i = 0
   def __call__(self, val):
       self.i += (val == self.val)
       return self.i
list2 = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(li, key=GroupbyHelper('abc'))]
print(list2)
```